# Unnecessary lookups for related fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a django model which looks like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    n = models.IntegerField()
```

My django-shell is configured to print all the sql queries as soon as it is fired.
So, writing

```
a = A.objects.get(id=10)
```

prints one query to retrieve an object from the table `A`.

What I do not understand is, that writing `print a.n` fires a query to retrieve the related `B` element.

Can anyone throw some light on why Django needs to retrieve the element `B` when I haven't even accessed it yet? (Nor do I plan to do so. So it is turning out to be an overhead for me.)

**Edit**

This is the original code that @Daniel asked for:

```
>> x=PlayedGamesModel.objects.get(pkey='i01E25D45526E14EA0A490D36@AdobeID16688802f8024509a8e431b644108a82')
[2014-03-05 12:46:15,174] (0.326) SELECT `appConnexions_playedgamesmodel`.`pkey`, `appConnexions_playedgamesmodel`.`user_id`, `appConnexions_playedgamesmodel`.`game_id`, `appConnexions_playedgamesmodel`.`playedFromBrowser`, `appConnexions_playedgamesmodel`.`playedFromConnexions`, `appConnexions_playedgamesmodel`.`deleted`, `appConnexions_playedgamesmodel`.`timestamp` FROM `appConnexions_playedgamesmodel` WHERE `appConnexions_playedgamesmodel`.`pkey` = 'i01E25D45526E14EA0A490D36@AdobeID16688802f8024509a8e431b644108a82' ; args=('i01E25D45526E14EA0A490D36@AdobeID16688802f8024509a8e431b644108a82',)
>> print x.playedFromConnexions
1
[2014-03-05 12:46:17,993] (0.319) SELECT `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`gameID`, `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`gameURL`, `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`title`, `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`longTitle`, `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`category`, `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`description`, `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`iconURL`, `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`screenshotURL`, `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`genre`, `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`minOS`, `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`price`, `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`isBlacklisted`, `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`swfURL`, `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`androidURL`, `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`windowsURL`, `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`iosURL`, `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`publisher_id`, `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`lastUpdated` FROM `appConnexions_gamemodel` WHERE `appConnexions_gamemodel`.`gameID` = '16688802f8024509a8e431b644108a82' ; args=(u'16688802f8024509a8e431b644108a82',)
[2014-03-05 12:46:18,597] (0.292) SELECT `appConnexions_usermodel`.`userID`, `appConnexions_usermodel`.`fID`, `appConnexions_usermodel`.`gID`, `appConnexions_usermodel`.`name`, `appConnexions_usermodel`.`avatarURL`, `appConnexions_usermodel`.`age`, `appConnexions_usermodel`.`country`, `appConnexions_usermodel`.`email`, `appConnexions_usermodel`.`settingsBitset`, `appConnexions_usermodel`.`allowLogin`, `appConnexions_usermodel`.`allowAutomaticAdd`, `appConnexions_usermodel`.`allowActivityShare`, `appConnexions_usermodel`.`logoutFromBrowser` FROM `appConnexions_usermodel` WHERE `appConnexions_usermodel`.`userID` = 'i01E25D45526E14EA0A490D36@AdobeID' ; args=(u'i01E25D45526E14EA0A490D36@AdobeID',)
```

`PlayedGamesModel` is the table with relations to `GameModel(appConnexions_gamemodel)` and `UserModel(appConnexions_usermodel)`. Printing an integer value (`playedFromConnexions`) from `PlayedGamesModel` fires queries to `GameModel` and `UserModel` unnecessarily.

Comment: Mayank, U want only `n` to be retrieved ?? then use `values_list` of query set . https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list . also have a look at `select_related` . You may need it later .

Comment: a = A.object.get(id=10) should actually trigger a query

Comment: Your description of the problem is quite wrong, as kanu points out: with `get`, the query is done immediately. But no query will be done to access `b` unless you ask for it. You need to go back and post your exact code, with examples showing the queries being fired.

Comment: Yes. That is incorrect. It does fire a query on the get statement itself. I confused it with a QuerySet.

But B is queried as soon as I print a.n. That is what I am unable to comprehend.

Comment: @PriyankPatel. Yes I know about select_related and values_list. I do not need to retrieve the entire B object. I just need it's id which should have been retrieved in b_id in the first query itself. I do not understand the relation between `print` and retrieval.

Comment: why worrying about an extra query? if there is a code which runs often then use values_list on that part, but usually this profiling / performance tuning should be done at the end of the software development

Comment: Thanks @tiborka. But I am at the end. Functionality is complete. Performance gain is what remains. I am trying to understand when django fires the query for a related field.

Comment: then fine tuning for those cases which are called often, as others said use values_list, and on demand instantiate the object B, it is said anyway with 20 percent/80 percent rule (20 percent code runs at the time of 80 percent)